# Objects Speed up when they move out of scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and have begun trying to recreate 'flappy bird' from scratch. The pipes when the move out of the game view, speed up then slow down.

Here is the code for the pipes:

```cs
public class PipeMoving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float slideSpeed = 5f;

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.left * slideSpeed, (ForceMode2D)ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why your object is slowing down is because you used force mode impulse, which will initially apply that force only once.... In order to fix it do ForceMode2D.Force, which will apply a constant force on that object.

Make the variable private and use SerializeField so it can be visible in the inspector panel and not accessed anywhere else...

```
[SerializeField]
private float slideSpeed = 5f;

void Awake()
{
    myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
     move();
}

void move()
{
    myBody.AddForce(new Vector2.left(slideSpeed,0), ForceMode2D.Force);
}
```

Set a variable myBody( or anything you prefer) as the rigidbody component so you can use it multiple times in your code more efficiently...

**Edits listed below:
I have included the keyword 'new' before Vector2.left(slideSpeed,0)

I did that because there is no pre-existing vector which is Vector2.left(slideSpeed,0) so you have to use the keyword new whenever you are declaring a vector for the first time.

If you are considering to reuse the vector, then you can declare it in the top of your code...

```
leftVector = new Vector2.left(slideSpeed,0);
```

On doing so, you don't have to use the new keyword when you will use the variable later, incase that confuses you...

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, when I use the code it says on the void move() Non-invocable member 'Vector2.left' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @fifavc19 slight correction to my code, use the keyword 'new' before Vector2...

The error is coming because there is no pre-existing vector which is Vector2.left(slideSpeed,0) so you have to use the keyword new whenever you are declaring a vector for the first time.